# PHP gzipping JSON, saving to memcache... Node.js serving - proper headers?

Tags: php, node.js, http-headers, memcached, gzip

In PHP I am doing something like:

```
$gzdata = gzencode(json_encode($data), 9);
$mc->set("latest", $gzdata);
```

So I pull my associative array from the DB, I turn it to JSON, Gzip it and store to memcache

In my Node.js I read the memcached entry and serve it (where client is memcache client)

```
client.get('latest', function(err, response) {
            if (err) { console.log("GET", err.type ); } 
            else{
                result.writeHead(200,{
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "content-encoding":"gzip"
                });


                result.end(response['latest']);
            }
        });
```

I am getting

> Content Encoding Error

on the page

> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an
>   invalid or unsupported form of compression.

I cannot even check the headers in FB... any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't gzipping normally done by your web server? Is it thus possible that you are serving content that is gzipped twice?

Comment: I know nothing (yet) about node.js, but looking at your code, you get 'latest', but then return 'result.end(response['latest']);'. Shouldn't you just return 'response'?

Comment: @BotondBalázs: node.js is my webserver in this case... it should serve already gzipped json... as as little overhead as possible

Comment: @DS_web_developer: sorry then. I don't know node.js. You could try checking the response in another browser. Maybe Chrome will give you more info. Or maybe try to get it with `curl`. You could also try giving different parameters to the `gzencode()` function - a different compression level maybe.

Comment: Chrome gives me this error:
Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error.

if I do this with mod_deflate in apache, I am getting more http response headers... on of them is content-length... could be the problem here?

@BotondBalázs: Thanks, I will check it with curl

Comment: is it possible, that memcache doesn't store the proper gzipped value?

Comment: @DS_web_developer: If I remember correctly, memcached values are binary safe so I don't think that's the problem

Comment: @Robbie: not with overclocked mc, check it out: http://overclocked.com/mc/#read

Comment: @DS_web_developer - OK that follows. Did you note the bit just below about adaptors? http://overclocked.com/mc/#adapters - string adaptor is the default, you probably want binary? `client.setAdapter(mc.Adapter.binary);` before the get?

Comment: @Robbie: I tried it to set to binary, but I am getting an error that ends the server. that setAdapter method doesnt exist :S

Comment: That doesn't sound good - may well be your problem. I'd dig around that area - check you have the latest version (1.0.6) throw in a string and see if you get the string back, then throw in an image and see if you get an image back, or if corrupted etc. Also, the docs say this: "Note: A major reworking to support the memcache binary protocol is underway.". Doesn't bode well. But there are two solutions: gzip in Node.js (memcached already has compression for storage, so only downside of not doing so is memory transfer bandwidth) or store in base64 (and decode in node?)

Comment: strings, arrays, jsons ..everything work just fine, except gzipped content :S

Comment: this content will be grabbed a lot. A LOT. and I don't want to load the CPU too much... as few calcs as possible... ideally it would be to gzip it to the memory and serve it directly, everytime prepared...doing the gzipping in node.js would be redundant, since it would have to do it EVERY time and it would show

Comment: + the binary adapter in mc does simply this: return results.buffer; I tried to do this directly on response['latest'].buffer but I get undefined

Comment: tried also using response.write(response['latest'], "binary"); no luck... I should check other compressing options in php

Comment: The result I get from node.js is as expected the same as I put in memcache... so the problem is not the content itself....it could be either the http header set in node.js either the wrong compressing method..... any ideas of how to rule both of them out?

Comment: You could try try ob_gzhandler (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php). Basically use the ob commands to trap the output, echo JSON, use that zip handler? Never tried it, but might work. Incidentally, are you checking that the briowser accepts GZIP? That seems a hole in your logic.

Comment: @DS_web_developer: could you solve this? I'm interested.

Comment: @Robbie: the browser accepts gzip (I have a css' and js' being deflated by apache and firebug shows correct headers for those, and are being shrunk)...  I tried also the ob_gzhandler... the output is the same as with gzencode... so it doesn't solve anything..

BotondBalázs: not yet... I've spent about 7h debugging this but still nothing. I gave up for now since I am swamped with work and will be back on this in few days. Will let you know

Comment: You could test if `"Content-Encoding":"deflate"` works and/or compress you content using `gzdeflate`

Answer (score 1):

Did you know that the Memcache client can already do compression for you?

```
$memcache_obj = new Memcache;
$memcache_obj->addServer('memcache_host', 11211);
$memcache_obj->setCompressThreshold(20000, 0.2);
```

This would compress values when larger than 20k with a minimum compression of 20%.

See also: [`Memcache::setCompressThreshold`](http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.setcompressthreshold.php)

Comment: sure I did.... but what good does this in my case? I want to compress JSON so I served the browser client already compressed json

Comment: @DS_web_developer I can get into that later; let me dig around a bit :)